# Kodein override binding for AndroidTest

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kodein

I want to override a Kodein binding by a mock before testing my class.

There is my Kodein init:

```kotlin
val kodein = Kodein {
    bind<MyRepository>() with provider { MyRepository() }
}
```

Then my class to test:

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    private val mMyRepository: MyRepository by kodein.instance()

    suspend fun sendData() = mMyRepository.sendData()
}
```

And my test class:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyClassTest {

    @MockK
    lateinit var mMyRepositoryMock: MyRepository

    val mMyClass = MyClass()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)
    }

    @Test
    fun testSendData() {
        coEvery { mMyRepositoryMock.sendData() } returns Unit

        runBlocking {
            mMyClass.sendData()
                .collect {
                    assertTrue(true)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to override `mMyRepository` value in `MyClass` during my test by `mMyRepositoryMock`.

Can somebody help me doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely why we do *not* recommend using a global Kodein instance.

The best way to ensure a class testability is to remove its context dependency.

Consider the following class:

```kotlin
class MyClass(override val kodein: Kodein) {
    private val mMyRepository: MyRepository by kodein.instance()

    suspend fun sendData() = mMyRepository.sendData()
}
```

Now the `kodein` it uses is passed as parameter, and can therefore be properly configured for tests:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyClassTest {

    @MockK
    lateinit var mMyRepositoryMock: MyRepository

    val kodein by Kodein.lazy {
        bind<MyRepository>() with provider { mMyRepositoryMock }
    }

    val mMyClass by lazy { MyClass(kodein) }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)
    }

    @Test
    fun testSendData() {
        coEvery { mMyRepositoryMock.sendData() } returns Unit

        runBlocking {
            mMyClass.sendData()
                .collect {
                    assertTrue(true)
                }
        }
    }
}
```